# How can I use properties in pom.xml in spring application context xml file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have a an spring context file which is similar to what is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
                location="classpath:application.properties, classpath:application-${env}.properties"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

The snippet of pom.xml where profiles are configured is as below-

```
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <env>test</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <env>prod</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

I want to use the property 'env' which is decided based on selected maven profile, in my spring application-context file.

How can I do that?

Edit:- Its a Spring web app

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: No you don't want to do that. You don't want to have different profiles for building your application. That basically means you are going to production with a different artifact as you tested, as you need to rebuild the whole application. Instead set en environment variable `env` and Spring will simply replace it. You can reuse the same artifact without having to rely on Maven.

Comment: Yes, we create different artefacts for different environments but the reason is more historical and change in this process will require change in deployment scripts as well. Trust me, I want to do that too :) Coming back to my question, my intention is to switch to different environment properties based on environment which is specified by maven profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question but, if you can use Spring Boot, I think what you are trying to do is easily solved by using [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

Essentially you avoid manually coding in the multiple profiles in Maven and in your XML and let Spring do it for you. [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/) is a basic example.

Comment: my project is not Spring boot, and to take it to Spring boot is not possible currently.

Comment: Profiles has nothing to do with Spring Boot, Profiles have been supported since Spring 3.1 long before the existence of Spring Boot.